# Read a string from pipe

Tags: c, linux, fork

I have the following code:

```
int pfds[2], pid;

if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, pfds) < 0) {
        goto error;
}

if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    goto error;

if (pid == 0) {
    /* child */
    close(pfds[1]);
    dup2(pfds[0], 1);
    close(pfds[0]);
    const char *argv[5];
    int i = 0;
    argv[i++] = "/bin/sh";
    argv[i++] = "/sbin/script.sh";
    argv[i++] = NULL;
    execvp(argv[0], (char **) argv);
    exit(ESRCH);
}
close(pfds[0]);
s.stream.string_data = true;
s.stream.notify_read = client_read_cb;
ustream_fd_init(&s, pfds[1]);
```

The script return a string (printed with `echo` command) that is mark the end of script loading.

How can I read the string returned by the `/sbin/script.sh` ?

Comment: `dup2(pfds[0], 1);` is weird.  Normally, you write to the write side of the pipe, and you read from the read side.  (ie, you expect to see `dup2(pfds[1], 1)`)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are missing the differentiation between child process which executes the execv and the parent process which will do the reading:

```
char readbuffer[100];

if(pid == 0)
   ...
else
{
    close(pdfs[0];
    nbytes = read(pfds[1], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
}
```

But if you just want to wait for the end of the script, you can just do a wait_pid on the child process.